# MMDrawerController navigating to another view controller when I click on the leftViewcontroller cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, mmdrawercontroller

I am implemented MMDrawerController for my application when I clicking in the leftView cell I need to navigate to another view controller as a new controller ,but if I am pushing the view controller its opening in the same left view only its not open as a new vc.

if I given presentviewcontroller. its not navigate to child view of my vc.

please help me .

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

> viewcontroller = Where you want to push the Screen..!
>
> Make sure mmDrawerController (object of MMDrawerController() ) has viewControllers , here mmDrawerController means where I initialized it first time . Like in appDelegate or etc..
>
> Check if it is nil or not: print(mmDrawerController.centerViewController)

```
@IBAction func btnTapped(sender:UIButton) {
        let viewcontroller = UIViewController()
        mmDrawerController.setCenterView(viewcontroller, withFullCloseAnimation: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you ... 
I am getting my new VC as a new CenterViewController ,
 my new VC is embedded with navihgationVC's navigation Bar not showing.

When I click on button in new VC-- my application crashing .
How to resolve this.

Comment: have you embeded your viewcontrollers with navigationController ?? try to check first that your navigationcontroller has viewcontrollers.

Comment: let say i have two ViewControllers , 1: LeftViewController and 2 : FrontViewController . now I initialized it in AppDelegate and assign their objects to two different navigationcontrollers and now i assigned that two navigationcontrollers object to MMDrawerController() , now next step is assign that object of MMDrawerController  to one new navigationController , make that newlly navigationcontrollers object to window's rootViewController.

Comment: And when you want to push your screen anywhere , just follow my answer which i described in @IBAction.

Comment: I don't know I missed that simple line .... tq @gopal.    Assigning navigationController a NewVC to  ,in story board I done but when I pushing time I did't  added navigation Controller.